# Creating a MySQL Stored Procedure To Add a File To End of Existing Table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will allow me to input a file, year, and string, and add it to the end of an existing table in MySQL.  However, when I attempt to call the program it does not recognize the input file as a variable in the FROM clause.  Does anyone have any tips for correcting this issue?  I'm new to creating SQL programs but have looked into dynamic SQL, and was wondering if that might be an alternative?  Thanks in advance for your help, and I'm happy to post any additional information.

Source File columns are ACS_Code and Descriptive_Title, 
Output table columns are Year, Data_Profile, ACS_Code, and Descriptive_Title.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `padata`.`Load_ACS_Data_Profile_Code_Def`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `padata`.Load_ACS_Data_Profile_Code_Def(IN file VARCHAR(255), IN Data_Profile Varchar(50), IN Year INT) # Input("Social","Economic","Housing",or "Demographic_Housing") for Dataprofile
BEGIN

INSERT INTO padata.ACS_5yr_Selected_Code_Definitions( 
        Year, 
        Data_Profile,
        ACS_Code,
        Descriptive_Title)
SELECT
        Year AS Year,
        Data_Profile AS Data_Profile,
        a.ACS_Code AS ACS_Code,
        a.Descriptive_Title AS Descriptive_Title
FROM 
    `padata`.file a ;  #Where file is a parameter that is passed

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And here is the call command and error information:

```
CALL `padata`.Load_ACS_Data_Profile_Code_Def ('2010_5yr_Selected_Social_Metadata', 'Social', 2010)
Error Code: 1146. Table 'padata.file' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is `file`, it seems to me you are referring to an file on your operating system. Don't say it is an input file. It is a varchar (string).

It certainly isn't a table in db called `padata`.

The stored proc IN means you are passing in a parameter such as a string, int sort of thing. It does not open up a stream reading from a file.

**Edit**:

```
drop schema so_gibberish;
create schema so_gibberish;

use so_gibberish;

create table thisTable
(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    favF int not null,
    fullName varchar(100) not null
);
insert thisTable (fullName,favF) values ('Jimmy Johnson',2),('Kelly Kipper',3);

create table thatTable
(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    favF int not null,
    fullName varchar(100) not null
);
insert thatTable (fullName,favF) values ('Jennie Jugggs',1),('Zach Zipper',4);

create table favFruit
(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    fruit varchar(100) not null
);
insert favFruit(fruit) values ('banana'),('kiwi'),('raspberries'),('honey dew melon');


DELIMITER $$ 
drop procedure if exists so_gibberish.doSomething$$

CREATE PROCEDURE so_gibberish.doSomething
(tblName varchar(100))
BEGIN
    SET @statement=concat('select p.fullName,f.fruit from ',tblName,' p join favFruit f on f.id=p.favF');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;


call doSomething('thisTable');

Jimmy Johnson   kiwi
Kelly Kipper    raspberries



call doSomething('thatTable');

Jennie Jugggs   banana
Zach Zipper     honey dew melon
```

Comment: here you go Alan, try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html  you can bring it into a table if it is comma separated values

Comment: good catch on noticing that OP was trying to use `file` as a parameter and thanks for answering my QU. +1

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I understand that you can just load data with a local INFILE command, but is it possible to use a file or existing source table as a parameter?  Or is that not a possibility with the stored procedures?

Comment: For a varchar that is a tablename, Yes , using Prepared Statements. I can bang out an example in a bit when off my android if that is what you mean.

Comment: That sounds great.  I think that is what I am looking for.

Comment: ok there you go. Prepared Statement in a stored proc, passing a tablename and does a join.

Comment: That worked wonderfully.  Thank you for such a thorough answer.  Very neat way to achieve what I wanted to.  Thanks so much for the help Drew.